# Push notification

Tags: php, api, magento, notifications, push-notification

How can we make a Magento notification service/API for more than 1 android devices for adding, deleting, and other operations.
If there are two or more devices then it should notify other devices in case one of the devices add, delete, or update a product, user, or category etc.
I am using Magento soap API. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you require to build this from scratch, you'll want to take a look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mobile.push.introduction.html . Magento already makes large use of the Zend Framework, so this would be the easiest solution to implement if having to build from scratch.

If you're open to an off the shelf solution, you will want to consider Magento Mobile ( http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/mobile ). It would be the quickest way to get what you want, and will likely cost less than implementing this API from scratch.

Built right in is a Push Notification Service with Urban Airship ( http://urbanairship.com/products/push-messaging ).

The solution would cover you immediately with Android, and if you needed coverage for iOS you could quickly implement that when needed.